# dataset for emotion detection

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a code using opencv library which is tracking the user's face and the features on the face. I have managed to do live detection of face and the features like eyes, lips from the webcam. I would like to now extract the emotion from the detected features. I would like to know is there any available dataset which I can use to compare the emotion and how it can be done.

here is the code for face detection

```
    CvRect detectFaceInImage(const IplImage *inputImg, const CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade )
{
    const CvSize minFeatureSize = cvSize(20, 20);
    const int flags = CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;    // Only search for 1 face.
    const float search_scale_factor = 1.1f;
    IplImage *detectImg;
    IplImage *greyImg = 0;
    CvMemStorage* storage;
    CvRect rc;
    double t;
    CvSeq* rects;
    int i;

    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );

    // If the image is color, use a greyscale copy of the image.
    detectImg = (IplImage*)inputImg;    // Assume the input image is to be used.
    if (inputImg->nChannels > 1) 
    {
        greyImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(inputImg->width, inputImg->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
        cvCvtColor( inputImg, greyImg, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        detectImg = greyImg;    // Use the greyscale version as the input.
    }

    // Detect all the faces.
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    rects = cvHaarDetectObjects( detectImg, (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cascade, storage,
                search_scale_factor, 3, flags, minFeatureSize );
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    printf("[Face Detection took %d ms and found %d objects]\n", cvRound( t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.0) ), rects->total );

    // Get the first detected face (the biggest).
    if (rects->total > 0) {
        rc = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( rects, 0 );
    }
    else
        rc = cvRect(-1,-1,-1,-1);   // Couldn't find the face.

    //cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
    //cvReleaseImage( &detectImg );
    if (greyImg)
        cvReleaseImage( &greyImg );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

    return rc;  // Return the biggest face found, or (-1,-1,-1,-1).
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using old OpenCV API, any specific reason for that? Have you succeeded in emotion detection using OpenCV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using the Karolinska Directed Emotional Faces (KDEF) photographs for an educational research project. Information regarding the data set is available at http://www.emotionlab.se/resources/kdef.

Note that you will probably need to crop, resize, center, straighten, and normalize the images to use them with OpenCV. Once properly prepared, the images work quite well with all the OpenCV2 FaceRecognizer class functions.

As to how facial expression recognition can be done: no standard approach exists. Start by reading the FaceRecognizer documentation and working through the tutorials. For what it's worth: I have found that using Local Binary Pattern Histograms produces the most accurate results.